# Update old database with SQL dump

Tags: recovery, mariadb

I had to recover a database with a some months old full backup. I have however in my possession a most recent but unfortunately incomplete SQL dump for this same database done with `mysqldump`.

Is there any tool out there that will allow me to compare my SQL dump with the live database and import any new data?

Comment: When you say "possession a most recent" you mean with additional content (rows), or with modified rows?

Answer (score 1):

import your dump with INSERT IGNORE OPTION (skip duplicates)

on your dump file (assuming you're using linux OS)

```
cat /path/dir/to/dumpfile.sql |
  sed s/"^INSERT"/"INSERT IGNORE"/g > /path/dir/to/newdump.sql
```

then issue import

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < /path/dir/to/newdump.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should import both dump's to MySQL Server, and then use

```
REPLACE INTO old SELECT * FROM new
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Import into two tables TABLEA and TABLEB
then compare the two using the following:

```
select * from tableA
minus
select * from tableB
```

If you get two result sets use

```
select * from tableA
except
select * from tableB
```

Comment: Do you know which versions support `minus` instead of `except`? Beyond that, this does cover the "comparison" aspect of the question, and might help someone determine if there's both new and updated records (which I don't think the answers cover the possibility of).